# Purpose of Abstract Methods in collections.abc

Tags: python, collections, abstract-class

The collections library provides abstract classes and their subclasses such as `MutableSequence` and it's super class `Sequence`.

What is  the necessity of abstract methods in the subclasses which are then forced to be defined in classes inheriting from them.  Why can't concrete methods be used instead?

Comment: So what would their implementation be?

Comment: Rationale in PEP 3119 is a good information source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what would the implementation of the concrete methods *be*?

The point of these classes is *not* to give you yet another list object. They exist to communicate what methods a class would need to implement to adhere to the given protocol.

For the container ABCs, they are not containers themselves; they don't actually hold anything. So you can't provide a concrete `__getitem__` method for a `Sequence`; there *is no internal state*. And providing an implementation that uses a `_list` attribute would dictate how a subclass should implement this, but a proxy class, just to name an example, would not have an internal sequence state.

Only methods that can be expressed in terms of other methods, such as `__contains__` (*return `True` if `__getitem__` doesn't raise an exception*) or `__iter__` (*use an increasing index and produce the result of `__getitem__` until it raises an exception*) have a concrete implementation for subclassing convenience.

Comment: would you be able to extend this answer to the purpose of virtual subclasses as well?  My understanding is the virtual subclasses is registered to the abstractclass/superclass as a means to pass type checks such as isinstance or issubclass - but why would anyone want to do this, why not create a true subclass?

Comment: @AranFreel: because you want to test for the *protocol*. Something that implements `__getitem__` and `__len__` can be used anywhere Python expects a sequence. That doesn't require inheriting however. You *do* want to test for those properties, so `isinstance(obj, Sequence)` is valuable.